# How to decode &lt;br&gt; in Java

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, html-parsing

In the website, http://web.mta.info/status/serviceStatus.txt, some of the tags are encoded, for example to `&lt;br&gt;`. I am wondering how I would decode these tags back to their normal format so that I could parse through and read them. The code that follows is what I current have.

```
String address = "http://web.mta.info/status/serviceStatus.txt";
XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;
XmlPullParser parser;
HttpClient httpclient;
HttpGet httpget;
URI website;
HttpResponse response;
HttpEntity httpEntity;
InputStream xmlFile;    

//code that just initializes some other variables

private void updater() {
    // try catch to catch any exceptions thrown
    try {
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        httpget = new HttpGet(address);
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        httpEntity = response.getEntity();
        xmlFile = httpEntity.getContent();

        pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();

        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(xmlFile, null);

        parseXML(parser);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

parseXML is basically to go through the file and find the information that I need.

Comment: You'll need an entity reference such as http://www.w3.org/2003/entities/2007/w3centities-f.ent. I've done this in C# but not Java.

Answer (score 0):

replace

`&lt;` with < 
`&gt;` with >

`&lt;` standsfor **<**
`&gt;` standsfor **>**

Those html entities were left in the code snippet on the site you mentioned, most due to a bug and this is how that site escapes code snippets.